# how to get the event object for onClick()

Tags: jquery

I have a loop which generates lot of input text fields with jquery. Now i want to fire stopPropagation method when someone clicks on those input tags. I am in a notion that this method works like this:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

But problem is that i want to fire this method on onClick attribute of the input tag. Like this:

```
$(handler).html('<input type="text" value="'+text+'" style="width:280px;" onClick=stopPropagation(); />');
```

And this won't work for obvious reasons. I need to get the event object for this click. Whats the smarter way?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'input', function(e){e.stopPropagation();});`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy You're going to stop their propagation, after they've propagated to `document`?

Comment: @alex could you show me what you mean? I don't see my event walking the tree, i see `querySelectorAll()` being called in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its easy, just add "event" key word to your onClick call, like so:

```
$(handler).html('<input type="text" value="'+text+'" style="width:280px;" 
    onClick=stopPropagation(event); />');
```

Then in your function:

```
function stopPropagation(event) { /* do work */ }
```

or you can do it the jQuery way:

```
$('input').on("click", function(event) { /* do work */ });
```

keep in mind, on your inline functions, just like the word `this`, `event` is a key word that tells the js your function should be getting an event argument

Finally you could just change the add all together:

```
var newInp = $("<input />").width(280).text(text);
$(handler).append(newInp);
newInp.on("click", function(e) { /* e is your event */ });
```

Comment: yes, thats what i was looking for. event keyword is what i actually wanted. Just out of curosity: is there a way we can do this like:  onClick=$(event).stopPropagation()

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it this way.

```
$('#id').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The smarter way is to not use inline event handlers at all:

```
var el = $('<input type="text" value="'+text+'" style="width:280px;" />');
$(handler).append(el);
el.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: @steveax Since the element is already added to the DOM, and there is no indication of there being more than one, I see no reason to delegate to the parent, especially since the whole reason he is stopping propagation might be to prevent the click handler on the parent firing.

Comment: he can also just use the event keyword, sometimes, depending on situation, cause and clause, it could be more beneficial to create it inline

Comment: @SpYk3HH What causes, clauses and situations might those be?

Comment: @Asad rules and restrictions laid upon one by the employer, standards a company might follow, regulations by a security department .... just to name a few

Comment: @SpYk3HH No company in the world will require of you that you use inline event handlers, I assure you.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `onClick=stopPropagation()`

you can use

```
$('#your_input_id').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```